# Cannot add label in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to add labels inside the JPanel.[image]

Below is the code and screen.

```
JPanel tableListPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        tableListPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
        tableListPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5),
                BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Added Tables")));

        PosButton btnRemoveTable = new PosButton("REMOVE");

      // code to add lable.
      tableListPanel.add(new JLable("Test")):
```

Comment: Where are you trying to add a label, I can't see this part of code ?

Comment: You have a `BorderLayout` for the panel, but you're not telling the panel where to add the label... NORTH, SOUTH, CENTER, ... ?

Comment: Also if you don't add it in the CENTER, the label should have a preferred size.

Comment: It should be tableListPanel.add(new JLabel("Test"));

Comment: It is that only.. even I tried with 
tableListPanel.add(new JLabel("test"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
but it din't work

Comment: Are you probably adding something else besides the label there? Each position in a `BorderLayout` can hold only one component.

Comment: can you please share full code for that panel? Is there anything else added into tableListPanel afterwards? Looks like maybe an empty JList? Please make also sure your code **compiles**. It's supposed to be JLabel not JLable and )): in that line needs to be ));

Comment: PosButton btnRemoveTable = new PosButton("REMOVE");
  btnRemoveTable.setFocusable(false);
tableListPanel.add(btnRemoveTable, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Comment: As [Jan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3480246/jan) already suggested, please help the people that are trying to help you: add a runnable example of your problem (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information). This will make reproducing and solving the issue a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
tableListPanel.add(new JLabel("Test")):
```

For:

```
tableListPanel.add(new JLabel("Test"), BorderLayout.WEST): 
//You can also use BorderLayout.EAST, BorderLayout.NORTH or BorderLayout.SOUTH
```

**EDITED:**

Might also want to change this (only if the first change does not work on its own):

```
JPanel tableListPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
```

For:

```
JPanel tableListPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

**EDITED 10/03/2017:**

Changed JLable for JLabel.